# Cumulative totals SQL

Tags: sql, date, cumulative-sum

I have a table for charges as below for each date

[image]

For each payment date as below, I need to calculate the expected amount and expected total amount based on the charges from the first table. For 02/10/2019, it is 1+2+3=6 (the charges after July until October). For 09/10/19 it should be the same as above as it's still October. For 08/01/20, 4+5+6=15. Can someone please help on how to achieve this. Thank you.

[image]

Comment: I removed the inconsistent database tags.  Please tag *only* with the database you are really using.  Also, you seem to have two tables, but it is unclear.

Answer (score 0):

One method is a correlated subquery:

```
select p.*,
       (select sum(c.netamount)
        from charges c
        where c.date <= p.paymentdate
       ) as expected
from payments p;
```

Comment: Thank you for your swift response. But I have some records with 2 payment dates in the same month and need to add them twice. In the example above, there are 2 payments of 6 each in October, so 12 need to be added to 17 to get 29. How do I do that?

Comment: @sparc . . . That is not the question you asked here: "For each payment date as below, . . . ".  If you have a different question, ask as *new* question -- and tag the database you are using.